# how to query SQL for a ISBN with dashes against one with no dashes.

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, search

how would I query a MySQL db for ISBN's in the format 000-0-0000-0000-0 against an ISBN with the same number of digits, but has no dashes? is there a SQL regex replace method that I can use or something? any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions at all.  Just use something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where replace(t.ISBN, '-', '') = @MyISBN;
```

Comment: +1 Was checking for a sargable solution, but that turns out to be no fun with ISBNs :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson . . . The question doesn't state where the other ISBN is coming from.  If it is a variable (as my answer suggests), then you are right -- putting the dashes in the right place would allow the use of an index.  But if it is from another table, then that doesn't help.